# Including MapKit in iOS SDK5 project with 4.3 target does not compile with ARC enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I´ve just started a new xcode 4.2 project targeting iOS 4.3

Once I add the MapKit.framework to my project it stops compiling and raises many ARC related error messages.

Do I have to disable ARC for MapKit?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you adding the framework?

Comment: By dragging the framework in from finder into the Frameworks folder.

Comment: Hm. The fourth time I tried starting a new project it worked without problems.

Comment: Try adding it via Xcode instead. Look in the Xcode user guide for your version of Xcode; you don’t need to drag it in.

Comment: Dragging in the framework worked in the end. Must have done something wrong the first three times.

Answer (score 0):

The -fno-objc-arc flag allows you to control which parts of your source are compiled with ARC: http://www.jameskelso.com/post/11878189130/using-non-arc-code-in-an-arc-enabled-project

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don´t know how to disable ARC specifically for MapKit source files since only the headers are included in my project. I guess since MapKit is a precompiled library I would have to turn off ARC for the files I have that reference to MapKit. Is this so?

Comment: Any pre-compiled frameworks shouldn't matter. Since they are already compiled, ARC v. no ARC doesn't matter since the appropriate retains and releases are added by ARC at compile time. Perhaps posting your error messages would help.

Comment: You do not need to disable ARC for MapKit, so this is not relevant and not helpful in solving this particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

No, you should not have to turn off ARC to use mapKit.

Comment: My question was rather: Do I have to disable ARC specifically for that framework.

Comment: And my answer is "no". To be sure I just created a project with ARC and mapKit and it compiled fine. Thank you for the down vote :)

Comment: I down voted it because it was not a very helpful answer. That's what the voting system is supposed to reflect.

Comment: How is it not helpful? It is the proper answer in simplest terms. He should NOT have to turn ARC off at all. Which you seem to agree with. My purpose here is not to get into a food fight with either of you, but suggesting turning off ARC for this is misleading and should NOT be mentioned. Nailer, there is something else wrong with you project.  The answer to you initial question is still "no" downvote all you like, but do not mislead other knowledge seekers.

Comment: In answer to your question, it is not helpful because the question was obviously intended to ask for help coming up with solutions. You did not do that.

Comment: QUESTION: "Do I have to disable ARC for MapKit?" and you feel that answering his question with a fact was not helpful? Yet, you answered with something misleading and that is? Do you think your answer will help future readers?